# Integer reduces to string when accessing via tostring/checkstring?

Tags: c, lua

Do integral values reduce down to strings in Lua? I've tried to track down a bug for almost a full hour, when I realized that numbers are the same as strings, given the following code:

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include "lualib.h"

int ex_dummyfunc(lua_State* L)
{
    const char* first = luaL_checkstring(L, 1);
    int second = luaL_checkinteger(L, 2);
    printf("first = %s, second = %d\n", first, second);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    lua_register(L, "dummyfunc", ex_dummyfunc);
    if(argc > 1)
    {
        if(luaL_dofile(L, argv[1]) == 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", lua_tostring(L, 1));
        }
    }
    lua_close(L);
    return 0;
}
```

test.lua:

```
dummyfunc("stuff", 42)
dummyfunc(42, 8)
dummyfunc(82, "stuff")
```

output:

```
first = stuff, second = 42
first = 42, second = 8
error: test.lua:4: bad argument #2 to 'dummyfunc' (number expected, got string)
```

*_**EDIT**_*:

Thanks to the [answer by Kevin Ballard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790956/integer-reduces-to-string-when-accessing-via-tostring-checkstring/4790999#4790999), and some googling on how typechecking is performed internally, i've noticed `luaL_checktype`, which allows token-based type enforcement. So, to enforce a string argument, the function `ex_dummyfunc` needs to be edited this way:

```
int ex_dummyfunc(lua_State* L)
{
    luaL_checktype(L, 1, LUA_TSTRING);
    const char* first = luaL_checkstring(L, 1);
    int second = luaL_checkinteger(L, 2);
    printf("first = %s, second = %d\n", first, second);
    return 0;
}
```

Why does Lua not throw a type error on the second call to `dummyfunc`?

Comment: What is the actual output when you run the program?

Comment: @Peter Lillevold: I've edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> const char *luaL_checkstring
>   (lua_State *L, int narg);
>
> Checks
>   whether the function argument narg is
>   a string and returns this string.
>
> This function uses [lua_tolstring](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_tolstring) to
>   get its result, so all conversions and
>   caveats of that function apply here.

In the documentation for lua_tolstring it says "The Lua value must be a string or a number". So no, Lua does not store strings and numbers the same internally, but yes, it does tend to convert between the two as necessary.

Comment: nuts... but I guess it can be enforced with `lua_checktype` somehow